# how to secure routes in API and in client with next-auth

Tags: express, next.js, next-auth

I run an backend and a frontend both served by express the backend on port 8080 and the frontend on port 80.

```
/api/route1        returns 200ok with json
/api/route2        returns 200ok with json
```

So the app works fine fetching these routes. Now to the thing I need your help with. I have added next-auth so in the frontend I can

```
const [ session, loading ] = useSession();
```

to do something like

```
{!session && <p>You are not logged in</p>}
```

which works but what I haven't figured out is how to protect the routes to the API. I want to protect route1 and route2 in both frontend and backend. I guess when I'm logged in a need to pass a token down to the API but how can I have these 2 talking to each other

```
/api/route1        returns 200ok with json
/api/route2        returns 200ok with json
```

Remember I run the backend and frontend separately because my production build is in docker that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an [example of this in the next-auth-example project](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example/blob/main/pages/api/examples/protected.js)

```js
// pages/api/examples/protected.js
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client'

export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req })

  if (session) {
    res.send({ content: 'This is protected content. You can access this content because you are signed in.' })
  } else {
    res.send({ error: 'You must be sign in to view the protected content on this page.' })
  }
}
```

If a session object exists (i.e. is not null) then it means they either have a valid session token (if using database sessions) or a valid signed JSON Web Token (if using JWT session).

In both cases the session token is checked to make sure it is valid and has not expired.

The request object `req` is passed through to `getSession()` call when used in this way so that the cookie containing the session token can be inspected and validated.

Answer (score -1):

The way that you could handle protected routes within Node is by using middleware.

So lets say that you have a route for adding employees salary in database, so obviously such a route needs someone that is and authenticated admin right?

- So you could make a middleware function like the simple one below

```
const validateAdminCookie = (req, res, next)=>{

    //Here you then write all your logic on how you validate admin
    
    //Now you will have conditonals here that:

    if (!validatedCookie){

        return res.status(400).json({msg:'Not authorized'})
    }

    next();
}
```

- So now that function is what you will pass within your route so that is gets executed first and when user is valid authenticated admin then the `next()` will push down that user to the main route that they were trying to hit else if not authenticated then the get back a message that they are not authenticated.

**Now how you pass this middleware is like this below:**

```
router.post('/api/admin-update-salaries',validateAdminCookie, (req, res)=>{

   //Now that **validateAdminCookie** will execute first and if all
   //checks out then user will be pushed down to the main part
   //that is this route here

})
```

Comment: The question is regarding next-auth